# ColdFusion2016 classpath issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I've installed a clean instance of ColdFusion2016. I'm copying my old settings over from a CF11 instance. I'm having problems with the 
ColdFusion Class Path in the Java and JVM settings of the ColdFusion administrator. A third-party jar that was fine on cf11 stops ColdFusion from starting. I know the path to the jar is correct. I've tried changing the jre to the latest version. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: The jar probably has an different version of a library that CF uses. You may be better off using `this.javasettings`

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the ColdFusion services after placing the new jar file ? 
Also make sure you are not using a jar compiled on java 1.7 or 1.6.

Comment: *not using a jar compiled on java 1.7 or 1.6* Why not? Typically compilation with *later* versions is problematic, not the other way around.